# В чем заключается разница подходов при добавлении/удалении entities в EF

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity

Есть условный контроллер, который из представления принимает объект класса Book. db в данном случае контекст.  Насколько я понял, запись можно осуществить двумя способами.

Первый:

```
    public ActionResult Create(Book newBook)
    {
        db.Entry(newBook).State = EntityState.Added;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

И второй:

```
public ActionResult Create(Book newBook)
    {
        db.Books.Add(newBook);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем разница подходов и какой из них предпочтительнее использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конкретно в данном случае разницы нет никакой. Предпочтительнее использовать тот, который лично вам понятнее.

---

Но в общем случае, операции `db.Books.Add(newBook);` и `db.Entry(newBook).State = EntityState.Added;` могут вести себя по-разному.

Метод `db.Books.Add(newBook);` проверит, что `newBook` еще не была добавлена в контекст `db`. Если загрузить книгу из базы, после чего добавить ее обратно - будет ошибка.

В то же время, присваивание `db.Entry(newBook).State = EntityState.Added;` ничего не проверяет. Если загрузить книгу из базы, после чего добавить ее обратно - получится копия записи в базе.

---

PS не вижу у вас создания переменной db. Надеюсь, она не статическая? Статический контекст EF - это серьезная ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо большое!
По хорошему надо было бы создать репозиторий, в котором операции с базой использовальсь бы в 

`using (BookContext db = new BookContext()){}`

Но в данном это лишь учебный пример :) 
Еще раз спасибо за ответ!